Commutative diagram involving order statistics
Given the random variables i.i.d. $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and their cdf $F$ I'm trying to explain why the following diagram is conmutative:
$$
X_1, \ldots, X_n \xrightarrow{\text{sort}} X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}\\
F \downarrow \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad F \downarrow\\
F(X_1), \ldots, F(X_n) \xrightarrow{\text{sort}} F(X_{(1)}), \ldots, F(X_{(n)})
$$
I don't understand how the composition $\text{sort} \circ F$ and $F \circ \text{sort}$ work. How can I relate $\text{sort} \circ F$ and $F \circ \text{sort}$?

I don't think there is anything special about random variables or CDFs here. For any list of distinct [non-random] numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and any increasing function $f$, we have $\text{sort} \circ f = f \circ \text{sort}$. This is because $u < v$ if and only if $f(u) < f(v)$.

It holds only if $f$ is strictly increasing.

@amir I think it works even if $f$ is only weakly increasing. It certainly works if $f$ is constant. Did you have a counterexample in mind?

It works because the cdf $F$ is an increasing function, that is:
$$X_1 < X_2 \iff F(X_1) < F(X_2)$$

It holds only if the cdf is strictly increasing.

@Amir Yes, agreed.
